# print statement after a while loop doesn't work in c

Tags: c

```
void generateReceipt(dailyTrans *dhead, itemStruct *ihead, int receiptNum){
    dailyTrans* current;
    current = dhead;
    itemStruct* i;
    int totNum;
    float itemTot;
    float tot;

    printf("Customer Receipt #%3d\n", receiptNum);
    printf("Code      Item Name         Price   NumItem        TotSale\n");
    while(dhead->nextTrans != NULL){
        i = SearchForItem(current->code,ihead);
        itemTot = i->itemPrice*current->num;
        printf("%4d      %-15s   %5.2f   %7d        %7.2f\n",current->code,i->itemName,i->itemPrice,current->num,itemTot);
        totNum += current->num;
        tot += itemTot;
        current = current->nextTrans;
    }
    printf("\n                              Totals:%5d        %7.2f\n",totNum,tot);
}
```

this is what it suppose to print:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHlJT.png)

This is what actually print:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgYKu.png)

Comment: I tried the fflush(stdout), but it didn't work

Comment: Probably a typo! This: `while(dhead->nextTrans != NULL){` should be this: `while(current->nextTrans != NULL){`. If you don't understand why, then I'll attempt an answer that explains.

Comment: While loop should be checking `current` not `dhead`. Also `totNum` and `tot` are not initialised.